# Change Label of Approval Button

Tags: approval-process

Can I change the name of the buttons associated with Approval Workflows?
I am using Approval workflows. The standard button says "Submit for Approval". Is it possible to change the words on that button to say something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This can be done by creating a new custom button and placing it on Page Layout 
Please follow the following steps

1: Place the Original approval button on your page layout.
2: Click Right mouse button on the "Submit for approval" button
3: Click on Inspect element
4: You will see the following code

```
<input value="Submit for Approval" class="btn" title="Submit for Approval" name="submit" onclick="if ((Modal.confirm &amp;&amp; Modal.confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?')) || (!Modal.confirm &amp;&amp; window.confirm('Once you submit this record for approval, you might not be able to edit it or recall it from the approval process depending on your settings. Continue?'))) navigateToUrl('/p/process/Submit?retURL=%2FXXXX&amp;id=XXXXXX','DETAIL','submit');" type="button">
```

5: Copy this piece of code and create a new custom button on your object ( For Example, I am showing on case object)
6: Create a new button - Give it a nice approval name :) - Choose for a "Detail Page Button" - Execute Java Script - Onclick Javascript

7: Paste your above code and delete the text from "
And change your numeric id to {!Case.Id} 

8: Place this new button on your page layout and test it.

I am attaching the screenshot for a similar button I added in Case Object.

Let me know in case you face any issues with it.
If this answer helps you , mark it as the best answer.

Comment: I am glad it helped you.